# Cannot change monologue views in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, monologue

I am using the monologue gem and monologue generated views.  I am trying to edit the views but nothing I write in any of the view files actually shows on the browser.  Here is the line in my routes file:

```
mount Monologue::Engine, at: '/blog'
```

and here is my monologue.rb file:

```
Monologue.config do |config|
  config.site_name = "My blog"
  config.site_subtitle = "my own place online"
  config.site_url = "http://example.com"

  config.meta_description = "This is my blog about..."
  config.meta_keyword = "music, fun"

  config.admin_force_ssl = false
  config.posts_per_page = 10

  # config.disqus_shortname = "my_disqus_shortname"

  # LOCALE
  config.twitter_locale = "en" # "fr"
  config.facebook_like_locale = "en_US" # "fr_CA"
  config.google_plusone_locale = "en"

  #config.layout               = "layouts/application"

  # ANALYTICS
  # config.gauge_analytics_site_id = "YOUR COGE FROM GAUG.ES"
  # config.google_analytics_id = "YOUR GA CODE"

  config.sidebar = ["latest_posts", "latest_tweets", "categories", "tag_cloud"]


  #SOCIAL
  config.twitter_username = "myhandle"
  config.facebook_url = "https://www.facebook.com/myhandle"
  config.facebook_logo = 'logo.png'
  config.google_plus_account_url = "https://plus.google.com/u/1/.../posts"
  config.linkedin_url = "http://www.linkedin.com/in/myhandle"
  config.github_username = "myhandle"
  config.show_rss_icon = true

end
```

For some reason, I can remove or add lines to any of the monologue view files, such as `views/blog/layouts/application.html.erb` and nothing changes.  I've tried uncommenting the line `#config.layout = "layouts/application` in the monologue.rb file and that takes away all styling from the browser (although the css files I've created are still being called and served in the browser) but still no changes in the html actually work. Why are none of my changes actually being reflected in the browser?

Comment: Anyone have an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit confusing on the monologue structure after the views get generated for the engine in your parent Rails application. I think there should be a automatic change on links, etc (as I posted here https://github.com/jipiboily/monologue/issues/294). Basically you've gotta use the parent applications layout and match it to your directory structure.